# VS Code Keyboard shortcut and Vim

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I created a keyboard shortcut for `Matchit: Jump Items` to run on <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> (`%`) when `editorTextFocus`.

[image]

I diid this so that I could easily jump from opening to closing tag in HTML. I use VSCode in Vim mode where that key binding will jump from opening to closing brackets/braces/quotes/whatever by default.

My problem is that now I cannot get a percent sign to appear in my code as when I type it, the cursor jumps to the closest closing element (tag, brace, bracket, etc). When I removed that shortcut, not only does it not jump from opening to closing tag, it no longer works for braces/brackets/quotes/whatever. Not sure why that is since it is built into Vim and does not require Matchit.

Is there a way to specify that the key binding should not apply when my cursor is in insert mode? or is there a better way to configure things so that I get that functionality (jumping to closing tag, quotes, paren, brace, etc), but can also actually type the `%` character?

Comment: I use `vim` natively so i don't know how it runs on VScode. But in native vim, `%` by itself jumps to open/close bracket without any key remapping in normal mode. Is this not possible in vscode without remapping?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Vim and you are not using Vim so I removed the tag. You should use the VSCode extension's issue tracker.